# как ускорить код на питоне с библиотекой pygame

Tags: python, pygame

мне надо ускорить код ниже до максимума, я ещё плохо знаю питон.

```
import numpy as np
import pygame
import random
import time
import threading





nach = 50000
h = 700
w = 800
speed = 2000


b = []
x = 0

fpstext = "0"

x = 0
y = 0

for x in range(nach):
    b.append([(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255)),random.randint(100,w),random.randint(0,h),5])
xb = 0
yb = 0


def keyses():
    global xb
    global yb
    while True:
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: yb += 1/speed
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: yb -= 1/speed
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: xb -= 1/speed
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: xb += 1/speed


def otr():
    global x
    global fpsr
    global screen
    global fpstext

    done = False
    tre1 = threading.Thread(target=keyses,daemon=True).start()
    tre2 = threading.Thread(target=oc,daemon=True).start()

    while not done:
        time1 = time.time()
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        try:
            screen.blit((fpstext),(0,0))
        except:
            pass
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
        for x in range(len(b)):
            pygame.draw.rect( screen, b[x][0] , pygame.Rect(b[x][1], b[x][2], 5, 5))
        pygame.draw.rect( screen, (random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255)) , pygame.Rect(xb, yb, 5, 5) )
        pygame.display.flip()
        time2 = time.time()
        try:
            fpsr = str(int(1/(time2-time1)))
            screen.blit((fpstext),(0,0))
        except:
            pass


def oc():
    global fpsr
    global fpstext
    global fps
    fpsr = "0"

    fps = pygame.font.SysFont("fps",30)

    while True:
        fpstext = fps.render(fpsr,False,(255,0,50))
        time.sleep(0.15)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
otr()
```

помогите пожалуйста, мой код даже показывает фпс, но при увеличении количества объектов (за кол-во объектов отвечает nach)
падает и фпс,но скорость должна помочь

Comment: Зачем numpy импортируете? Где он используется?

Comment: @Глеб библиотеки что-то нагружают?

Comment: Нет, они на скорость вряд ли влияют, только на память. Просто интересно. Без надобности библиотеки лучше не импортировать.

Comment: @Глеб но может вы всё-же знаете как ускорить или оптимизировать этот код

Comment: Почитайте, как использовать спрайты и группы в pygame. И потоки нужны, когда есть длительная операция замораживающая основной цикл. Цикл со sleep можно заменить таймером.  Ну а цикл с обработкой событий клавиш, должен быть в основном цикле.

Comment: Ну, почитайте [тут](https://www.codepins.net/snippets/pygame-how-to-regulate-fps) или [тут](https://questu.ru/questions/67977386/), может, это вам поможет.

Comment: Когда разгоните код pygame стандартными методами, можно применить векторные операции с `numpy`, затем `JIT`-компиляцию с помощью `Numba`, и если этого будет не хватать, то вишенкой на торте будут графические `Shader`.